# Include and namespace in php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I have created this factory class:

```
namespace ValidatorFactory;

foreach (glob("Types/*.php") as $filename)
{
    include $filename;
}

class ValidatorFactory
{
    public static function getValidator($betTypeId)
    {
        switch ($betTypeId)
        {
            case 1:
                return new B();
                break;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my A abstract class definition:

```
abstract class A
{
    abstract function validateSchema($schema);
}
```

Here is my B class definition:

```
class B extends A
{
    function validateSchema($schema)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now I want to use the factory class in some other file in my project, here is how I am doing it:

```
$obj = ValidatorFactory::getValidator($someId);
```

I am using Laravel and via composer (and [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2MLepOlT9Q&list=UUpOIUW62tnJTtpWFABxWZ8g)) I tried to load the `ValidatorFactory` class like built in classes of laravel. Here is what I have added to the composer file:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "ValidatorFactory": "app/"
    }
},
```

I have run `composer update`.

My problem is that my ValidatorFactory is not loaded because I am getting this error:

```
Class 'ValidatorFactory' not found
```

If I will add the namespace like this:

```
$obj = ValidatorFactory\ValidatorFactory::getValidator($someId);
```

I am getting other error, here it is:

```
Class 'ValidatorFactory\B' not found
```

So there are 2 problems, first related to larave/composer autoload (of the namespace). The second is related to includes and inheritance (as I suspect) in php.

How can I solve this two issues? Thanks!

**Update:**
As suggested in the answer, I have added the same namespace for all 3 involved classes A, B and the factory. No class including any other class.

In the class which calls the factory's `getValidator` function I am doing it like this:

```
$obj = ValidatorFactory\ValidatorFactory::getValidator($someId);
```

Still getting the error which says class B is unknown :(

Here is how the updated class B looks like:

```
namespace ValidatorFactory;
class B extends A
{
    function validateSchema($schema)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The file structure looks like this: factory file located in `app/dir1/` , Class A and B located in `app/dir1/dir2/`

Comment: Can you tell us more about your class B? What is its filename, where is it in the folder structure, do you have a `namespace ...` (and what namespace is it) above your `class B extends A`, etc.

Comment: And the `B` class file is at `app/B.php`?

Comment: No, it is : factory file located at `app/dir1/` , Class A and B located at `app/dir1/dir2/`

Comment: Ah that's the problem then. PSR-0 expects that it finds all the classes under namespace `ValidatorFactory` in `app/` as you defined in composer.json. Try move class A and B to `app/` to see if it works. Then talk about better structure after it works.

Comment: I have moved all 3 files to `app/` but now i am getting this: `Class 'ValidatorFactory\B' not found`. The error I happening in the factory class, at this line: `return new B();`

Comment: Have you done `composer dump-autoload` or maybe `composer update` after that? Composer will need to walk through your folders again to pick up the new files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57441/discussion-between-vlio20-and-unnawut).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our [chat discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57441/discussion-between-vlio20-and-unnawut), we couldn't figure out why PSR-0 is not working for you. It turns out that PSR-4 configuration works fine. So I summarise here what we did in the discussion to use PSR-4 autoloading.

**File structure:**

```
app
 |- commands
 |- config
 |- ...
 |- MyValidator
    |- MyValidatorFactory.php
    |- A.php
    |- B.php
 |- ...
```

**MyValidatorFactory.php**

```
namespace MyValidator;

class MyValidatorFactory
{
    ...
    return new B();
    ...
}
```

**B.php**

```
namespace MyValidator;

class B extends A
{
    function validateSchema($schema)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And finally you can setup PSR-4 autoloading in your **composer.json**:

```
"autoload": {
    ...
    "psr-4": {
        "MyValidator\\": "app/MyValidator"
    }
}
```

---

**Bonus point:**

With the psr-4 configuration above, you may also structure your namespaces and classes like this:

```
app
 |- commands
 |- config
 |- ...
 |- MyApp
    |- Validators
        |- MyValidatorFactory.php
        |- A.php
        |- B.php
 |- ...
```

And set the psr-4 config to `"MyApp\\": "app/MyApp"`, the autoloader will recognise your classes and use it like below:

```
new \MyApp\Validators\MyValidatorFactory;
new \MyApp\Validators\A;
new \MyApp\Validators\B;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
One thing, why we need to name `"psr-4": {
        "MyValidator\\": "app/MyValidator"
    }` with double slashes 'MyValidator\\'?

Comment: Hmm  actually the only thing that might be wrong with the psr-0 we used was the double trailing slashes! https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4. They are for "to avoid conflicts between similar prefixes. For example Foo would match classes in the FooBar namespace so the trailing backslashes solve the problem: Foo\\ and FooBar\\ are distinct."

Comment: In the tutorial, he didn't add any slashes. why then we need to add them?

Comment: From my understanding if you set `"Foo" : "app/Foo"` and `"FooBar" : "app/FooBar"`, and you have classes `Foo\MyClass` and `FooBar\MyClass`. You might end up getting `app/Foo/MyClass.php` when accessing `FooBar\MyClass`. The `Foo\\` makes sure that it does not also match for `FooBar` namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Anything defined in an `include` is defined in the [global namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1459311/697370), so the abstract class definitions define the `\A` and `\B` classes, respectively (and *not* `ValidatorFactory\A` or `ValidatorFactory\B`).  In order to use them the way you are, you would need to add a `use` statement for each of them after they are included.

But why include anything at all?  This goes agains the very idea of an autoloader.  If you want to declare a class, put it in one of your namespaces and let Laravel and composer do the hard work for you.

**Update**

```
return new B();
```

Try changing that line to:

```
return new \B();
```

And that will clear up your second error.  As for the first, you declared your Validator factory to live in a namespace:

```
namespace ValidatorFactory;
```

*Any* code that uses that class (which is *not* in the same namespace) will need to either A) import the class with a `use` statement, or B) use the Fully-Qualified Namespace whenever referencing it:

```
use ValidatorFactory\ValidatorFactory;

// ...

$factory = new ValidatorFactory();
```

**Or**

```
$factory = new ValidatorFactory\ValidatorFactory();
```

Remember, all namespaces are for is to allow you and another developer to name a class exactly the same thing.  For instance, perhaps I'm working on some sort of route mapping tool.  I may want to define a `Route` class, because that name fits extremely well with my current problem domain.  However, Taylor already beat me to the punch because there already is a `Route` class.  Using a *name* *space* I can ensure that I can still name anything I want whatever I want however I want to and there won't be any conflicts with stuff that has already been named or stuff that has yet to be named.

**Update 2**

Namespaces in projects using composer need to mirror the directory path in which the underlying files are located (this is how the autoloader can find them- it basically looks at the namespace and classname and turns that into a directory path to the file, and appends a `.php` extension).  If you have classes like this:

```
// File: app/dir1/dir2/A.php
class A{}

// File: app/dir1/dir3/B.php
class B{}
```

Then A will have to be in the namespace `dir1\dir2`, and its fully qualified name would be `dir1\dir2\A`.  Similarly, class B would have to be in the namespace `dir1\dir3` and its fully qualified name would be `dir1\dir3\B`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but why the composer not loading the namespace as it supposed to?

Comment: It's not supposed to load the namespace, you still must use the namespace or include a `use` statement, or you can modify your `config.php` file and add an alias for it so you can use it however you want.

Comment: If you will see the tutorial, the only thing that he did in order to include the namespace in the composer autoload is to add it in the composer. no config file editing.

Comment: @vlio20 he's just giving you another option. Laravel will let you make aliases so that referencing classes inside of the IoC container is easier.  I don't think you need to worry about that too much.

Comment: @watcher, I have set a namespace to the factory class and have added it to the composer, still I can't access it without the prefix. Why?

Comment: He prefixed his class in that tutorial with the namespace.  He had `return new Acme\Foo->bar()`.  When he added it to the autoloader, he was then able to take out the `require appPath()...` portion so you could see the class was being autloaded, but he still had to prefix it with the namespace.  To clarify, what composer is doing is loading the classes by the namespace, so it's searching all files for the namespace of Foo in the path you gave it and if it finds that namespace, it will then load that file.

Comment: One more thing, I am now getting: `Class 'B' not found`. I have added the name space to A, B and the factory class. Why?

Comment: If you added the namespace to class B, then your invocation should be `return new B();` (because its no longer in the global namespace)

Comment: @watcher, So in the factory I should do this: `return new B()` and not `return new \B()`? in both cases I am getting this error: `Class 'ValidatorFactory\B' not found` or `Class 'B' not found`

Comment: Make sure you have `namespace ValidatorFactory;` in both your class a and class b files and run `composer dump-autoload` so they get loaded.

Comment: @user3158900, I have added the name space to all 3 classes but still getting the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: All those classes reside in the same folder?

Comment: @vlio20 Can you update your question with what the code you have so far resulting from this answer?

Comment: @user3158900, no the factory is in 'app/dir1/' and A,B are in 'app/dir1/dir2/'.

Comment: That's your problem then.  They still aren't being loaded because the namespace for `A` and `B` should be `ValidatorFactory\dir2` and in your `ValidatorFactory` class, be sure you have the statement `use ValidatorFactory\dir2;` then you should be able to use them like `new A()` or `new B()` inside `ValidatorFactory`.  This might help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146057/composer-autoloader-psr-0-namespaces

Comment: For testing as @Unnawut, has suggested I have moved all 3 files to app/ but now i am getting this: Class 'ValidatorFactory\B' not found. The error I happening in the factory class, at this line: return new B();. My composer has this: `"psr-0": {
            "BetTypeValidatorFactory": "app/"
        }`